# React Package for Zoom and Pan Canvas

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I want to find a package that **handles zooming and panning on a canvas**. For those that have used **Figma**, *just* like that. Does this make sense? If you know of any, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Try [react-touch-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-touch-canvas)

This is a set of two React higher order components, for hooking mouse and touch events panning/zooming functionality into your application.